# Plans to upgrade spring-data-elasticsearch to latest version 2.x?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-elasticsearch

I want to build an application that is using ES as its back-end to store JSON documents. When looking at the GitHub repo, I noticed that the latest version of spring-data-elasticsearch is "only" supporting ES 1.7.3. However, ES is already at 2.1.0 and version 2 has some significant improvements, especially with better performance and stability.

So, I was wondering if there are any plans to upgrade this spring-data module and support ES 2.x anytime soon?

Comment: I'm waiting, too. Sure that 1.7.3 is supported?

Answer (score 0):

In the comments of jira task [DATAES-211](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-211) it is said that the plan is to use Elasticsearch 2.x with the Spring data Hopper release. But according to the GitHub page of Spring data [GitHub page of Spring data](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Hopper), there is no release date for Hopper yet.

Comment: The mentioned links have been updated and as it seems the 2.2 support has been implemented. GA for the Hopper release is scheduled for March 18th, 2016.